# Extract IP from a range with Terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to extract IP addresses from a range with Terraform.

For example, I defined this range `192.168.1.10-192.168.1.20` as a string and I would like to get a list like this: `[192.168.1.10,192.168.1.11,…,192.168.1.20]`.

I checked for [Terraform functions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions.html) but didn’t find a way to do that.

Is this possible?

For further context, I am deploying MetalLB in a Kubernetes cluster and need to define the VIP range as a string like this `192.168.1.10-192.168.1.20`.
The Kubernetes cluster is deployed on OpenStack and I need to configure Neutron OpenStack port to accept all IP addresses from this range:

```
resource "openstack_networking_port_v2" "k8s_worker_mgmt_port" {
  name           = "k8s_worker_mgmt_port"
  network_id     = data.openstack_networking_network_v2.k8s_openstack_mgmt_network_name.id
  admin_state_up = "true"

  allowed_address_pairs {
      ip_address = "192.168.1.10"
    }

  allowed_address_pairs {
      ip_address = "192.168.1.11"
    }
  }
....
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve with the output from this? You can probably do this with some mixutre of `range`, `formatlist` and some other functions but there might be a better approach to your overall goal if you can share that part too.

Comment: In your example you just change last number in the IPs. What about situation like this: `192.168.1.10-192.168.2.10`? Also not all IP addresses are usuable even if you generate such list.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, i edited my post to add context

Comment: Thanks. And from the input `192.168.1.10-192.168.1.20` you want a list starting with `192.168.1.11` and ending with `192.168.1.20` right?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yes, exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can rely on the first 3 octets of the IP range being the same then you can get away with using a combination of [`split`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/split.html), [`slice`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/slice.html), [`join`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/join.html), [`range`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/range.html) and [`formatlist`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/formatlist.html) functions to do this natively inside Terraform with something like the following:

```
variable "ip_range" {
  default = "192.168.1.10-192.168.1.20"
}

locals {
  ip_range_start = split("-", var.ip_range)[0]
  ip_range_end   = split("-", var.ip_range)[1]

  # Note that this naively only works for IP ranges using the same first three octects
  ip_range_first_three_octets = join(".", slice(split(".", local.ip_range_start), 0, 3))
  ip_range_start_fourth_octet = split(".", local.ip_range_start)[3]
  ip_range_end_fourth_octet   = split(".", local.ip_range_end)[3]

  list_of_final_octet  = range(local.ip_range_start_fourth_octet, local.ip_range_end_fourth_octet)
  list_of_ips_in_range = formatlist("${local.ip_range_first_three_octets}.%s", local.list_of_final_octet)
}

output "list_of_ips_in_range" {
  value = local.list_of_ips_in_range
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
list_of_ips_in_range = [
  "192.168.1.10",
  "192.168.1.11",
  "192.168.1.12",
  "192.168.1.13",
  "192.168.1.14",
  "192.168.1.15",
  "192.168.1.16",
  "192.168.1.17",
  "192.168.1.18",
  "192.168.1.19",
]
```

If you need to offset that range so you end up with IP addresses from `.11` to `.20` from the same input then you can do that by changing the `local.list_of_final_octet` like so:

```
  list_of_final_octet  = range(local.ip_range_start_fourth_octet + 1, local.ip_range_end_fourth_octet + 1)
```

Unfortunately Terraform doesn't have any built in functions for doing more elaborate CIDR math beyond [`cidrhost`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/cidrhost.html), [`cidrnetmask`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/cidrnetmask.html), [`cidrsubnet`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/cidrsubnet.html), [`cidrsubnets`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/cidrsubnets.html) functions so if you have more complex requirements then you may need to delegate this to an external script that can calculate it and be called via the [`external` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source).